# Unable to access nested routes directly in AWS amplify app

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have deployed my react typescript frontend on AWS Amplify, but I am umable to access nested routes

For instance:
I can open https://example.amplifyapp.com and then navigate to https://example.amplifyapp.com/login by clicking on the login button, but if I try to load https://example.amplifyapp.com/login directly, the browser gives me a 404 error.

Is there something that I need to add to my code, or is it an Amplify issue?